# Explanation needed on how Dependency Injection works in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

i am learning [nest.js](https://nestjs.com/). This is the project structure i have.
I have added [TYPEORM](https://typeorm.io/) to the project.
I am bit confused on how the DEPENDENCY INJECTION works in Nest.js.
In

**Project Structure**

```
|-APP_MODULE
  |-app.controller.ts
  |-app.module.ts
  |-app.service.ts
  |-AUTH_MODULE
    |-SIGN_UP_DTO
      |-signup.dto.ts
    |-auth.controller.ts
    |-auth.module.ts
    |-password-hash.service.ts
  |-USER_MODULE
    |-user.controller.ts
    |-user.module.ts
    |-user.service.ts
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validationSchema: envValidationSchema,
      validationOptions: {
        allowUnknown: true, // allows unknown env variables
        abortEarly: true, // aborts if env validation fails
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'sqlite',
        database: configService.getOrThrow('DATABASE_NAME'),
        entities: [],
        synchronize: configService.getOrThrow('DATABASE_SYNC_TABLES'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
      }),
    }),
    PostModule,
    CommonModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  ) {}

  getAllUsers(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.userRepository.find();
  }

  getOneUserById(id: number) {
    return this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });
  }
  getOneUserByEmail(email: string) {
    return this.userRepository.findOneBy({ email: email });
  }

  createUser(newUser: Partial<UserEntity>): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
}
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('users')
@Unique('user_email_unique', ['email'])
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  salt: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => PostEntity, (post) => post.user)
  posts: PostEntity[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;

  constructor(partial: Partial<UserEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

---

1. Scenario - 1 (Not Working)

**user.service.ts** is exported from **user.module.ts** and is added to the providers array **auth.module.ts**, but it is showing me error

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserEntityRepository at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.
```

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [PasswordHashService, UserService], // -> Injecting UserService is giving error
  exports: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

---

2. Scenario 2 (working)

**password-hash.service.ts** is exported from **auth.module.ts** and is added to providers array of **user.module.ts**, this is working without any error

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, PasswordHashService], // -> Injecting PasswordHashService(no error)
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [PasswordHashService],
  exports: [PasswordHashService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Needed clarification on how DI works in nestjs.

Comment: Can you please add the code of UserService, the error is caused there. Also what is UserEntityRepository?

Comment: @ka_lin added user.service.ts and user.entity.ts code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an explination of Dependecy Injection but...i faced same issue, using scenario 1...

Add your user.entity to auth.module on TypeOrmForFeature().

Even if you try to export your service, the service cant export the entity that he needs (user.entity).

Thats why you need to import the user.entity on your AuthModule because you are trying to use a service on a different module and this service on the new module cant access to the user.entity.

Just add TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]) on your AuthModule.

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  providers: [PasswordHashService, UserService], // -> Injecting UserService is giving error
  exports: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a module is a wrapper of dependencies. You should think of a module as a black box. That being said,

Why doesn't the first scenario work? Basically, you're declaring that `AuthModule` has a dependency `UsersService` but you aren't declaring the dependencies of `UsersService` (for that reason, scenario 2 works). What are the dependencies of `UsersService`? they are:  `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])]`. How to fix this? You should import `UsersModule` in **auth.module.ts** in this way:

```
auth.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule], // This import makes UsersService available within this AuthModule
  providers: [PasswordHashService],
  exports: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

It would allow to use `UsersService` within `PasswordHashService` or `AuthController`. Why do we have to import `UsersModule` instead of `UsersService` ? Because let's say that you have more than one provider with a lot of dependencies in `UsersModule` when you import the module, you're getting all you need to run the module without importing all the dependencies.

Comment: when i went through docs, it is said that whenever we generate a service, the service is tied to nearest module it is declared. so in that case PasswordHashService should not be imported directly, instead we need to import complete module. but is not the case in scenario 2,